# What is the best way to handle conditionally required arguments in a FastAPI app?

Tags: python, rest, web-development-server, fastapi, pydantic

I am developing a FastAPI application. I have with the following schema

```
class Address(BaseModel):
    address_string: str = Field(None)
    address_street: str = Field(None)
    addres_number: str = Field(None)
```

I like to have the field address_string conditionally required if address_street and addres_number are not present, and vice-versa, address_street and address_number are required if address_street is not present.

Currently I manage this by making all fields optional and using a root_validator to check the consistency, and documenting this conditional requirement in the description of the involved fields.

Is there a cleaner way to manage this built-in on FastAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root validators, or validators on the optionally required fields are the beat solution.

Similar example on passwords [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/).